# Sustituir string de parámetro de la URL con .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Tengo esta URL en algunas de las secciones de mi web en Joomla:

```
http://miweb.com/index.php?option=com_component&view=contracts&ff=1&id=20977&token=8f8c54a3ce165332fd59f17319ba
```

El caso es que no quiero que los usuarios vean el nombre: `com_component` cuando accedan desde el enlace. Necesito sustituirlo por otro string

`com_component`  -->  `com_nuevonombre`

He editado el archivo .htaccess, activando mod rewrite y tengo esto:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)com_component(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1?%1com_newname%2 [R=301,L]
```

Casi he conseguido lo que quiero, me sustituye el string, pero el error que tengo es que me añade la ruta local a mi proyecto delante. ¿Cómo lo puedo corregir? También acepto otras soluciones si se os ocurren.

La url que me muestra tras el error es algo así:

```
http://miweb.com/var/www/html/miweb/index.php?option=com_nuevonombre&view=contracts&ff=1&id=20977&token=8f8c54a3ce165332fd59f17319ba
```

Comment: Si no querés que aparezca en la URL, por qué enviarlo como parámetro? Podrías enviarlo por POST por ejemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asegurate de tener bien configurado el Document Root en tu `httpd.conf`.

```py
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/miweb
```

Reiniciá Apache para que tome la configuración.

En tu .htaccess, agregá estas 2 líneas antes de las reglas (normalmente no hace falta, pero funciona en los casos en los que Apache no puede determinar la carpeta en la que está):

```py
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Además, **nunca** uses una redirección 301 hasta haberlo probado y estar completamente seguro de que funciona bien. Las redirecciones con 301 son fuertemente cacheadas. Deberías probar con:

```py
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?]option=)com_component((?:[&?]|$).*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1com_newname%2 [R=302,L]
```

y modificarlo a un 301 cuando no haya ningún error, y estés seguro de que no se va a modificar en el futuro.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y funciona a la perfección! Era justo lo que buscaba y he resuelto mi error. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!